# RegEx how to modify to accept only 1 digit between 1-9 JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

RegEx how to modify to accept only 1 digit between 1-9 JavaScript

```
var numericReg = /^\d*[0-9](|.\d*[0-9]|,\d*[0-9])?$/;
```

I have tried to insert {0,1} in different parts of this RegEx but it stopped working. any tips??

valid example = `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `7`, `8`, `9`

invalid example = `0`, `10`, `11`, `1111`

Comment: post some valid and invalid examples.

Comment: sometimes, starting from scratch is easier than hacking bits off a more complex example :p

Comment: Why are you trying to insert the regex which matches a single digit into the above regex?

Comment: I need it to validate an input in a field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need one digit between 1-9, then you should use:

```
var numericReg = /^[1-9]$/;
```

Answer (score 0):

To explicitly specify exact length

```
^[1-9]$
```

Comment: `{1}` is quite unnecessary.